# Puppet: SSL certificate Error

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, puppetmaster

I did this

```
sudo puppet agent --test
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

I deleted the ssl directory but nothing help. I read the docs and none seem to work out. Any suggestion where to tackle?

the client is signed on the master.

Thanks.

---

Is time sync? I checked `date` and they both seem okay.

```
openssl x509 -text -in /var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/...
```

Weird... I don't have ssl directory?
What should I use to generate? There are too many commands ... I just wan to be careful.

This is the log for running `sudo puppet master --debug --no-daemonize`:
http://pastebin.com/TM3KHmzx

Then on client

```
admin@client:~$ sudo puppet agent --test
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Connection refused - connect(2)
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Here is my `fileserver.conf`

```
[blueprint1234]
path /etc/puppet/modules/blueprint1234/files
allow 10.10.0.0/12
```

Did I put the IP right? The internal IP of the client (it is a VM) is `10.10.0.12`
Here is the `site.pp`

```
node blueprint1234 {
        include blueprint1234
}

node 'client' inherits blueprint1234 {
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Since puppet has the least helpful error messages I've ever come across on a program, you might want to do the following for us to try and help you: Stop your puppet master, then type `puppet master --debug --no-daemonize` on the console and run it. Then run the puppet agent. When you start seeing errors on the `Master`, copy and append them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common cause for that is that the time of both machines are different by more than a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I've dealt with this a bunch of time and the solution that usually works is doing an `rm -r on /var/lib/puppet/ssl` (or whatever the ssldir is) on the puppet client (i.e. where you are running puppet agent commands). Then, on the puppet master, run `sudo puppetca --clean FQDN` where FQDN is the fully qualified domain name. That means not just `blueprint1234` but `blueprint1234.yourdomain.com` or whatever. If you don't get any output from the clean command, then you don't have the correct name...if it worked you'll seeing something about removing the certificate that you specified.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a similar error. The problem I had was my hostnames were all messed up may just double check